# Solr to get latest version of documents

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, solrj

I have a docs as follows:

```
{docid:1,version:1}
{docid:1,version:2}
{docid:2,version:1}
{docid:2,version:2}
{docid:2,version:3}
{docid:3,version:1}
{docid:3,version:2}
```

I need to get all the docs which are of latest version per each docid.

o/p

```
{docid:1,version:2}
{docid:2,version:3}
{docid:3,version:2}
```

Can give some hints on it how to do it.